# Using an Object Page Layout in custom aura:component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, page-layout

I would like to be able to create an `aura:component` that acts like the standard Record Detail for an Account Object. It should display the fields with edit buttons that allows for saving changes while respecting the Account Object page layouts and the assigned layout for roles and record type. Now I have gotten close with the use of a `lightning:recordForm` using `objectApiName="Account" layoutType="Full mode="View"` but it did not correctly render the page layout sections and blank spaces. Is there a different way to go about doing this?

Comment: I'm assuming you're asking this because you are unable for some reason to use the out-of-the-box Record Detail component on the object's Lightning record detail page for what you're trying to accomplish. Is that right?

Comment: Yes sir. I essentially need to tie some events to the record detail page so that other custom components used and visible on the lightning page containing all of this can remain in sync with each other.